# What is sitecore\virtualssuser

Tags: concurrent-users

I see a number of sitecore\virtualssuser "logged in" in /sitecore/shell/sitecore/client/Applications/LicenseOptions/KickUser

Anyone know what they are and if they are using Editor license place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sitecore/virtualssuser (Virtual ScreenShot User) is a virtual user used by the pre-emptive screenshot generation event handler. Being a virtual user, the user should never be persisted or appear in the user manager as it's not a real user account. In addition, the virtual user is destroyed once the screenshot generation has completed.

It is used by Content testing: https://doc.sitecore.net/products/sitecore%20experience%20platform/content%20testing